# High RAM after USB port shortcircuit

Tags: windows-7, memory, troubleshooting, hardware-failure

My Computer was displaying "USB Device Over Current Status" at startup and wouldn't boot. I believed the issue was related to a damaged USB port on the case - potentially shortcircuiting?. I disconnected the port and it booted fine into Windows.

I noticed once in Windows RAM usage was nearly maxed out (3.9Gb), It lowered slightly to about 2.7Gb until i opened one explorer window and it climbed right back up to the maximum usage. I'm assuming this likely means the RAM was damaged by the shortcircuiting (?) USB.

Does this sound about right?
Would anything else also likely to be damaged? How would I check?

Comment: what process is using the ram? Faulty ram ought not to do that, it should just not work.

Comment: i think 'searchfilterhost.exe' its using 1,634,916 KB (commit) according to resource monitor. It looks like at regular intervals 'searchprotocolhost.exe' uses a similar amount maxing out the RAM